# user access to multiple record types

Tags: permissions, record-type, custom-profile

Currently we have two record types A & B.Users are having access to either record A or B depending on their profiles.
Can a user have access to both record types.How it can be done.?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the user's profile add the record types A and B, following the link:
[Assign Record Types to Profiles in the Original Profile User Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/admin_recordtype.htm)